# print outputs in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to printout results from the return function. Could you please show me why I got the error message:

```
<function piecewise at 0x106a12840>
```

What is the right way to print out the result from a function?

Thanks.

```
units={}

g=9.81
units['g'] = 'm/s**2'

# Mass density of water
rho_w = 1031.
units['rho_w'] = 'kg/m**3'

# Mass density of oil
rho_oil=859.870
units['rho_oil'] = 'kg/m**3'

# Heat capacity
cp_w =  4185.5
units['cp_w'] = 'J/(kg*K)'

# Expansion coefficient of water
alpha_w = 2.0e-4
units['alpha_w'] = '1/K'

# Dynamic viscosity of water
mu_w = 1.08e-3
units['mu_w'] = 'Pa*s'

# Kinematic viscocity of air
nu_a = 1.48e-5
units['nu_a'] = 'm**2/s'


def get_R(d, rho=rho_w, delta_rho=(rho_w-rho_oil), g=9.81, mu=mu_w):
    ''' Gets the R variable, used to calculate rise velocity '''
    import numpy as np
    Nd = 4*rho_w*delta_rho*g*(d**3)/(3*mu_w**2)
    conds=[ Nd<=73, (73<Nd)*(Nd<=580), (580<Nd)*(Nd<=1.55e7) ]
    funcs=[]
    funcs.append( lambda Nd: Nd/24 - 1.7569e-4*(Nd**2) + 6.9252e-7*(Nd**3) - 2.3027e-10*(Nd**4) )
    funcs.append( lambda Nd: np.power(10, -1.7095 + 1.33438*np.log10(Nd) - 0.11591*np.log10(Nd)**2) )
    funcs.append( lambda Nd: np.power(10, -1.81391 + 1.34671*np.log10(Nd) - 0.12427*np.log10(Nd)**2 + 0.006344*np.log10(Nd)**3) )
    return np.piecewise(Nd, conds, funcs)

print(np.piecewise)
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. You define a function, but never call it. Then you print a Numpy function, but don't call it.

Comment: The last call, `print(np.piecewise)`, is not right -- I believe you mean `print(get_R(d))`

Comment: Thanks @wovano -- I just noticed that (I had Numpy already imported in a notebook)

Comment: @MarcelB The "error" is `<function piecewise at 0x106a12840>`. It's not shown in the OP cause they didn't apply code formatting to it (so it's interpreted as an HTML tag). I submitted an edit to fix it.

Comment: That is not an error. That is the string representation of the object you pass to „print“ - which happens to be the function „piecewise“. If you want the result of calling the function, *you must call the function*.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function in python, you get back what the function return. In this code, make sure to import numpy and assign a value to variable d:

```
result = get_R(d, rho=rho_w, delta_rho=(rho_w-rho_oil), g=9.81, mu=mu_w)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

your import

```
import numpy as np
```

is located inside your function **get_R**. You should move your import to the top of your file in order to make `np` available.

If you want to print the output of your function, do something like

```
print(get_R(123))
```

Comment: And that's probably only part of the solution, since `print(np.piecewise)` isn't really useful (as pointed in a comment by @TrevorKeller).

Comment: I tried next to run 'print get_R(123)' and it printed 0.0 without error so I suppose this solves the problem